# Non static link on the member Error C2352

Tags: c++, winapi, firebreath

Good day.
I'm writing a plugin with FireBreath. Tiny problem occurred due to my poor C++ knowledge, please see the code below.

I can't understand, why function `FB::PluginWindowWin::getBrowserHWND()`, that returns `HWND`
don't want to work as `HWND` for `GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect)` function.

Compiler underlines `FB` from `FB::PluginWindowWin::getBrowserHWND()` and tells me that
"non static link on the member has to be specified rather set object" (This is my translation, message is on Russian, but i believe it still got the same meaning)

Got this error:

```
Error C2352 FB::PluginWindowWin::getBrowserHWND:illegal call of non-static member function
```

Code:

```
TestPlugin.cpp
#include "Win/PluginWindowWin.h" 
#include "JSObject.h"
#include "variant_list.h"
#include "DOM/Document.h"
#include "global/config.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include "TestPluginAPI.h"

///////My Functions////////

FB::variant PosTest()
{
RECT rect; 
HWND hWnd;
hWnd = FB::PluginWindowWin::getBrowserHWND();
if(GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect))
    {

  int width = rect.right - rect.left;
  int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
  int left = rect.left;
      return left;
    }
}


TestPlugin.h
#include "Win/PluginWindowWin.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>
#include "JSAPIAuto.h"
#include "BrowserHost.h"
#include "TestPlugin.h"
#include <Windows.h>

/////Declarations/////

//Rect
BOOL WINAPI GetWindowRect(HWND hWnd, LPRECT lpRect);

//Pos Test
FB::variant PosTest();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error would indicate that `getBrowserHWND()` is not a `static` method, and therefore it requires an object instance to call it.

In other words, you need to have an object of type `FB::PluginWindowWin`, then you could call it like:

```
hWnd = myPluginWindowWin.getBrowserHWND();
```

Comment: I've never used Firebreath, so I won't be able to be very specific. I think you need to find some sample code in the Firebreath documentation and follow it. But looking at a blog at http://colonelpanic.net/2010/11/firebreath-tips-drawing-on-windows/, it appears FB should call your event handlers and pass in a pointer to a `PluginWindow`, which you can then cast to a `PluginWindowWin` and call `getBrowserHWND()`.  I think you should have written a class that extends `PluginCore`.  If so, you can call `this->getWindow()` in one of its methods to get a `PluginWindow`.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thx Nate, will try to mess with it.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me very well:

```
HWND myPluginAPI::getBrowserHwnd() {
    FB::PluginWindow* pluginWindow = getPlugin()->GetWindow();
    FB::PluginWindowWin* w = (FB::PluginWindowWin*)(pluginWindow);
    HWND hwndBrowser = GetAncestor( w->getHWND(), GA_ROOTOWNER );
    return hwndBrowser;
}
```

Comment: I can't man not enough reputation)
Well, the last thing, can you show me how your `getPlugin()` works?

Comment: What do you mean by "how works..."? The getPlugin() function is automatically created in your source when you launch a new FB project via the framework...

Comment: Hm.. the problem is that it gives me C2227 left of '->GetWindow' must point to class/struct/union/generic type and C3861 GetPlugin: identifier not found. I thought it's your custom function from your class, but now I'm confused.

Comment: Did you build your plugin like in the video tutorial through processing fbgen.py!?

Comment: Am yes, I'm pretty sure.
Thats weird.

Comment: Note that the code provided assumes that you're inside your JSAPI object (the one that extends FB::JSAPIAuto) and that you generated the project with fbgen.py and didn't remove the getPlugin helper function that is there by default